# VS Code is complaining about an Error TS7013 but Typescript isn't

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, interface, compiler-errors, new-operator

I have the following interface in my Typescript/Angular project

```
export interface MyInterface {
  new (helper: MyInterfaceHelpers);
}
```

When I compile the project, I get no errors at all from the Typescript compiler. 
However VSCode underlines it with squiggly lines and presents an error saying:

```
Construct signature, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7013)
```

Why does VS Code complain but Typescript doesn't? Where does this divergence in error checking happen? And finally, how do I get VS Code to stop complaining ?

Comment: I don't know if VS Code takes into account typescript compiler configuration of you project. Maybe you have a more relaxed tsconfig in unusual place, or maybe VS Code doesn't care about configs in your project?

Comment: VS Code definitely takes into account tsconfig.json It uses the one that's in the closest ancestor directory to the file you are editing. But doesn't go beyond root folder in your VS Code file browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VScode is complaining when you have `noImplicitAny: true` configured in your tsconfig.json file. Also because this is THE default setting for `strict: true`. so if you want to turn it off, you need to explicitly overwrite it as `noImplicitAny: false`.

You can check the detailed explanation in [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

However, a better way to make this error go away is to explicitly add a return type, ideally a strongly defined type, or even just `any`, makes it better than the implicit variation.

```
export interface MyInterface {
  new (helper: MyInterfaceHelpers): any;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But then why doesn't Typescript complain? Why only VS Code ?
(Btw just a correction, according to the docs, the default for `noImplicitAny` is `false`. )

Comment: Yes, nice catch. I mean to say default to true when strict mode is on `strict: true`. I think tsc compiler not complaining about it because it's not going to cause any issue to your application but rather not following the best practice. Although I can't find any solid resources explaining it in details.